# View model with properties that represent years and months

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model with properties that represent years and months:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years
{
    get
    {
        return new SelectList(
            Enumerable.Range(1900, 112)
            .OrderByDescending(year => year)
            .Select(year => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Text = year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            }
        ), "Value", "Text");
    }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
{
    get
    {
        return new SelectList(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .OrderByDescending(month => month)
            .Select(month => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = month.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Text = month < 10 ? string.Format("0{0}", month) : month.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            }
        ), "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

I definitely use copy & paste approach here.  How can I refactor this code? Maybe somehow passing the numbers as parameters to some helper method?

Comment: You don't need to order anything here, `.Reverse()` is simpler and more efficient. Also, do you really want to have the months backwards, or is that a copy & paste error?

Comment: thanks @svick! I really do not need orderByDescending here))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a format string to ensure that there are at least 2 digits in the format without having to check first.  The format: `{0:00}` ensures there are at least 2 digits, but allows for more.  It will prefix 0 to any single-digit input.

`string.Format` also has an overload which takes in an `IFormatProvider`, so my personal preference is just to collapse that into the `string.Format` call.  It also happens to line up nicely :)

With that, you can create a method with appropriate parameters which can handle both cases:

```
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years2 { get { return BuildList (1900, 112); } }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months2 { get { return BuildList (1, 12); } }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BuildList (int start, int count)
  {
     return new SelectList (
         Enumerable.Range (start, count)
         .OrderByDescending (val => val)
         .Select (val => new SelectListItem
         {
            Value = val.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = string.Format (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:00}", val)
         }
     ), "Value", "Text");
  }
```

Note: I suffixed my properties with 2 so I could run them side-by-side and compare results to be sure I didn't miss anything.

Note2: as Jesse suggests, you should ideally cache the results.

Comment: This feels like too much sharing for the format part to me. Just because you know that years are always going to have at least 4 digits doesn't mean you should use the `00` format for them.

Answer (score 2):

You're over-creating these objects on each call. Cache static values:

```
    private static readonly IEnumerable<SelectListItem> years = new SelectList(
        Enumerable.Range(1900, 112)
        .OrderByDescending(year => year)
        .Select(year => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        }),
        "Value",
        "Text");

    private static readonly IEnumerable<SelectListItem> months = new SelectList(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
        .OrderByDescending(month => month)
        .Select(month => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = month.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = month < 10 ? string.Format("0{0}", month) : month.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        }),
        "Value",
        "Text");

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years
    {
        get
        {
            return years;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
    {
        get
        {
            return months;
        }
    }
```

As for creating a helper method? I likely wouldn't. These mean two different things - years and months. Keep that logic separate.

Answer (score 2):

I dislike the way you specify your year range, especially the upper bound. It looks like you want the current year as upper bound, and not a magic value of `112` years since the start.

`112` is bad in two ways:

1. Its meaning isn't clear by itself, it only becomes the year `2011` when you look at the start value `1900`
2. You probably need to update it every year. It seems unlikely that you want to have a constant upper bound of `2011` forever.

I'd use something like:

```
int startYear = 1900;
int endYear = DateTime.Today.Year;

var years = Enumerable.Range(StartYear, endYear - startYear + 1).Reverse();
```

Potentially factoring out the current date/year to a property of the current viewmodel or a service so your helper method doesn't access any external mutable state (`DateTime.Today`).

Comment: thanks! it's a great insight to use DateTime.Today.Year;